# What's the equivalent of Ruby's pnormaldist statistics function in Haskell?

Tags: ruby, haskell, statistics, hackage

As seen here: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Here's the Ruby code itself, implemented in the [Statistics2](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/statistics2/) library:

```rb
# inverse of normal distribution ([2])
# Pr( (-\infty, x] ) = qn -> x
def pnormaldist(qn)
  b = [1.570796288, 0.03706987906, -0.8364353589e-3,
       -0.2250947176e-3, 0.6841218299e-5, 0.5824238515e-5,
       -0.104527497e-5, 0.8360937017e-7, -0.3231081277e-8,
       0.3657763036e-10, 0.6936233982e-12]

  if(qn < 0.0 || 1.0 < qn)
    $stderr.printf("Error : qn <= 0 or qn >= 1  in pnorm()!\n")
    return 0.0;
  end
  qn == 0.5 and return 0.0

  w1 = qn
  qn > 0.5 and w1 = 1.0 - w1
  w3 = -Math.log(4.0 * w1 * (1.0 - w1))
  w1 = b[0]
  1.upto 10 do |i|
    w1 += b[i] * w3**i;
  end
  qn > 0.5 and return Math.sqrt(w1 * w3)
  -Math.sqrt(w1 * w3)
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward to translate:

```
module PNormalDist where

pnormaldist :: (Ord a, Floating a) => a -> Either String a
pnormaldist qn
  | qn < 0 || 1 < qn = Left "Error: qn must be in [0,1]"
  | qn == 0.5        = Right 0.0
  | otherwise        = Right $
      let w3 = negate . log $ 4 * qn * (1 - qn)
          b = [ 1.570796288, 0.03706987906, -0.8364353589e-3, 
                -0.2250947176e-3, 0.6841218299e-5, 0.5824238515e-5, 
                -0.104527497e-5, 0.8360937017e-7, -0.3231081277e-8, 
                0.3657763036e-10, 0.6936233982e-12]
          w1 = sum . zipWith (*) b $ iterate (*w3) 1
      in (signum $ qn - 0.5) * sqrt (w1 * w3)
```

First off, let's look at the ruby - it returns a value, but sometimes it prints an error message (when given an improper argument).  This isn't very haskellish, so
let's have our return value be `Either String a` - where we'll return a `Left String` with an error message if given an improper argument, and a `Right a` otherwise.

Now we check the two cases at the top:

- `qn < 0 || 1 < qn = Left "Error: qn must be in [0,1]"` - this is the error condition, when `qn` is out of range.
- `qn == 0.5        = Right 0.0` - this is the ruby check `qn == 0.5 and return * 0.0`

Next up, we define `w1` in the ruby code.  But we redefine it a few lines later, which isn't very rubyish.  The value that we store in `w1` the first time
is used immediately in the definition of `w3`, so why don't we skip storing it in `w1`?  We don't even need to do the `qn > 0.5 and w1 = 1.0 - w1` step, because
we use the product `w1 * (1.0 - w1)` in the definition of w3.

So we skip all that, and move straight to the definition `w3 = negate . log $ 4 * qn * (1 - qn)`.

Next up is the definition of `b`, which is a straight lift from the ruby code (ruby's syntax for an array literal is haskell's syntax for a list).

Here's the most tricky bit - defining the ultimate value of `w3`.  What the ruby code does in

```
w1 = b[0]
1.upto 10 do |i|
  w1 += b[i] * w3**i;
end
```

Is what's called a fold - reducing a set of values (stored in a ruby array) into a single value.  We can restate this more functionally (but still in ruby) using `Array#reduce`:

```
w1 = b.zip(0..10).reduce(0) do |accum, (bval,i)|
  accum + bval * w3^i
end
```

Note how I pushed `b[0]` into the loop, using the identity `b[0] == b[0] * w3^0`.

Now we could port this directly to haskell, but it's a bit ugly

```
w1 = foldl 0 (\accum (bval,i) -> accum + bval * w3**i) $ zip b [0..10]
```

Instead, I broke it up into several steps - first off, we don't really need `i`, we just need the powers of `w3` (starting at `w3^0 == 1`), so
let's calculate those with `iterate (*w3) 1`.

Then, rather than zipping those into pairs with the elements of b, we ultimately just need their products, so we can zip them into 
the products of each pair using `zipWith (*) b`.

Now our folding function is really easy - we just need to sum up the products, which we can do using `sum`.

Lastly, we decide whether to return plus or minus `sqrt (w1 * w3)`, according to whether `qn` is greater or less than 0.5 (we
already know it's not equal).  So rather than calculating the square root in two separate locations as in the ruby code, 
I calculated it once, and multiplied it by `+1` or `-1` according to the sign of `qn - 0.5` (`signum` [just returns the sign of a value](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:signum)).

Answer (score 5):

Digging around on Hackage, there's a number of libraries for statistics:

- [hmatrix-gsl-stats](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-gsl-stats) -- a pure binding to GSL
- [hstatistics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hstatistics) -- an even higher level interface to GSL
- [hstats](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hstats) -- common statistical methods
- [statistics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics) -- more common statistical methods
- [statistics-linreg](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-linreg) -- a linear regression between two samples, based on the other statistics package.

You want a version of `pnormaldist`, which "Returns the P-value of normaldist(x)".

- [Statistics.Distribution.Normal](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/statistics/0.8.0.5/doc/html/Statistics-Distribution-Normal.html), from the statistics package, provides many functions for manipulating normal distributions.
- [Statistics.Test.NonParametric](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/statistics/0.8.0.1/doc/html/Statistics-Test-NonParametric.html) contains a number of things to do with [P-values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value).

Perhaps something there provides what you need?

Comment: I really know nothing of statistics :P. Do you know which of those functions is equivalent to pnormaldist?

Comment: I don't think any of those functions is exactly what you need.  You need the inverse of the erf function, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

The function you want is now available in the erf package on hackage.  It's called `invnormcdf`.

Answer (score 1):

here is my Wilson's score confidence interval for a Bernoulli parameter in node.js

```
wilson.normaldist = function(qn) {
    var b = [1.570796288, 0.03706987906, -0.0008364353589, -0.0002250947176, 0.000006841218299, 0.000005824238515, -0.00000104527497, 0.00000008360937017, -0.000000003231081277,
        0.00000000003657763036, 0.0000000000006936233982
    ];
    if (qn < 0.0 || 1.0 < qn) return 0;
    if (qn == 0.5) return 0;
    var w1 = qn;
    if (qn > 0.5) w1 = 1.0 - w1;
    var w3 = -Math.log(4.0 * w1 * (1.0 - w1));
    w1 = b[0];

    function loop(i) {
        w1 += b[i] * Math.pow(w3, i);
        if (i < b.length - 1) loop(++i);
    };
    loop(1);
    if (qn > 0.5) return Math.sqrt(w1 * w3);
    else return -Math.sqrt(w1 * w3);
}

wilson.rank = function(up_votes, down_votes) {
    var confidence = 0.95;
    var pos = up_votes;
    var n = up_votes + down_votes;
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    var z = this.normaldist(1 - (1 - confidence) / 2);
    var phat = 1.0 * pos / n;
    return ((phat + z * z / (2 * n) - z * Math.sqrt((phat * (1 - phat) + z * z / (4 * n)) / n)) / (1 + z * z / n)) * 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby code is undocumented; there is no specification of what this function is supposed to do. How does anyone know whether it does correctly whatever is intended?

I wouldn't just blindly copy and paste this arithmetic from one implementation to another (like the author of the Ruby package did).

A citation is given as `([2])` in a comment, but this is dangling. We find it in the comment block of the native C code in the `_statistics2.c` file.

```
/*
   statistics2.c
   distributions of statistics2
   by Shin-ichiro HARA
   2003.09.25
   Ref:
   [1] http://www.matsusaka-u.ac.jp/~okumura/algo/
   [2] http://www5.airnet.ne.jp/tomy/cpro/sslib11.htm
*/
```

Very sloppy work to only cite the C source code from where the coefficients were cribbed, rather than the original source of the formula.

The `[1]` link doesn't work any more; server not found. Luckily, the one we want is `[2]`. This is a page in Japanese with some C code for various functions. References are given. The one we want is `pnorm`. In the table, the algorithm is attributed to 戸田の近似式 which  means "Toda's Approximation".

Toda is a common surname in Japan; more detective work is required to find out who this is.

After much effort, here we go: paper (Japanese): [The Minimax Approximation for Percentage Points of the Standard Normal Distribution (1993)](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jappstat1971/22/1/22_1_13/_pdf) by Hideo Toda and Harumi Ono.

The algorithm is attributed to Toda (I'm assuming the same one that is the paper's co-author), dated to 1967 on P. 19.

It seems fairly obscure; the likely rationale for using it in the Ruby package is that it was found in source code of domestic origin citing the name of a domestic academic.

Answer (score 0):

A brief look on hackage didn't reveal anything, so I suggest you translate the ruby code to Haskell.  It's simple enough.